# ssh_exchange_identification: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.

Tags: ssh

if I try t connect to my remote server via SSH I get stuck to this, and I can't figure out how to going on.

```
tiziano@tiziano-HP ~ $ ssh -Tvvv -p 21 username@example.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to example.com [10.10.10.10] port 21.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/tiziano/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/tiziano/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/tiziano/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tiziano/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tiziano/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tiziano/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tiziano/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.3
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)


debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
```

Obviusly the username and the domain(ip addres) showed above are fake, I changed them.

Comment: The `-T` option is to disable pseudo-TTY allocation. And any particular reason you're using the default `telnet` port (21) instead of the default `ssh` port (22)?

Comment: Yes, the "T" option was something that I found around, but I saw that doesn't change anything. Because I have no route for port 22, but yes for port 21

Comment: Dumb question: is the server then configured to use 21 for SSH as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ssh -Tvvv -p 21 username@example.com
```

Port 21 is is the default port for [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol). You're connecting to an FTP server, not an SSH server. The "530 Please login with USER and PASS" message is a typical FTP server error message.

The default port for [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Usage) is 22, not 21.